# Intellij unable to resolve references to a specific jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

In a given project that is driven by sbt there is some kind of corruption in the project libraries specifically for a MavenLocal repository used for kafka-spark-9.7.2.jar in which:

- references to the classes provided by that jar are marked as "symbol not found" by the editor parser
- however the editor (strangely) does offer to import the classes
- but after accepting the import, the symbols are *still* marked in red as unresolved.

[image]

The following attempts to "clean things up" have already been performed:

- Build | Make Project
- Build | Rebuild Project

In addition I have verified that the project *does* build from

```
sbt package
```

on the command line

**UPDATE**  After re-running sbt gen-idea  the librraries are still not found by the Parser. yet the libraries exist -even IJ knows about them as shown in the following screenshot.  Why is it that IJ can find the library

```
C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.kafka\kafka\jars\kafka-0.7.2-spark.jar!\kafka\api\FetchRequest.class
```

However IJ is unable to resolve any classes from that library in the Parser?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build the project for Intellij, try to do this in your project root:

```
sbt idea with-sources=yes
```

This should build the project structure from scratch and add the right dependencies, usually I refresh the project after adding a dependency or a `jar`.

Edit:
To use the command you need this [plugin](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea), otherwise you can use `gen-idea` but I used it only a few times and I'm not sure how it will work out.

Edit2:

There was some confusion, first, for the IDEA SBT console you don't need to prepend the sbt command since you already are inside sbt:

[image]

If you have the sbt plugin for idea you can use `gen-idea with-source=yes` (without prepending sbt)

[image]

From the terminal, either you go to your project root and type `sbt` to enter the sbt console and use `gen-idea` or `idea with-sources=yes` (without prepending sbt)

[image]

or directly `sbt gen-idea` or if you have the plugin `sbt idea with-sources=yes` (prepending sbt)

[image]

To reach the sbt console inside idea you need to install the sbt plugin on preferences -> plugin and search for sbt and then View -> Tool Windows -> SBT Console:

[image]

To start the console click on the play button, to kill the console on the skull.

Comment: ah yes i had read (multiple times .. d'oh!)  that it is required to rebuild that way. Funny thing though - i have added dependencies dozens of times already and not had to do this manual (cmd line ) rebuild.  I wonder what were different in this case..  Maybe local maven repo??

Comment: AFA "with-sources=yes?" :  I need a "best effort but do not fail".Does the question mark achieve that? The sources are not available for .. you guessed it .. kafka.

Comment: I think you mean sbt gen-idea ..  Also: what about the "optional" aspect of including sources?

Comment: Also it appears to be sbt gen-idea sources

Comment: Pls read all of my comments : your answer is still incorrect in two ways.

Comment: This approach did NOT work.  The errors still remain.

Comment: The `with-source`command reload the dependencies form scratch and rebuilds the `XML` files inside the `.idea` and the `iml` inside the `.idea_modules` folders. Regarding the `gen-idea` command, it has no `with-source` equivalent (nor a `source` command don't know how you found it out), if you are inside `sbt` you can tab and see all the available options.
Usually this is the right way to load new jar/dependencies inside Intellij, it's hard to say why it's not working out for you. One thing you can is to search for the jar name inside `.idea` and `.idea_module`

Comment: So the command is different between IJ-sbt console and external dos-prompt sbt ?

Comment: I tried the idea SBT console and it looks the same, the only difference is that to trigger the reload project request you have to kill the console (the skull on the left), with the terminal instead the request is prompted immediately.

Comment: We are not 'connecting' here it seems. (a) The command "sbt idea with-sources=yes" does not work on command line   (b) The command "idea" or  "sbt idea" does not work in the sbt console Tool Window inside of IJ. Maybe you can post more details on your answer about how to execute the command.

Comment: Ah! I see now! There are in fact two different sbt idea plugins. That is why we are talking past each other.

Comment: How to display the sbt window or  sbt console in IJ? I can not find it except by doing "search anywhere"?  Never mind I manually added key shortcuts.

Comment: This was not a perfect answer (different versions of sbt plugin) but the only one so I will award at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by directly writing the `CLASSES` and `SOURCES` of the problematic library. This can be found in `.idea/libraries/SBT__<problematic library>_jar.xml`